# React controlled component input value with empty string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I wrote a demo below for the test `React` `controlled component` `input` feature. But It seems there is a bug.

```js
class TestComponent extends React.Component{
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {value: 'beef'};
    this.handleValueChange = this.handleValueChange.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleValueChange(e) {
    this.setState({value: e.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <div><input type='text' value={'hello world'} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
      <div><input type='text' value={''} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
      <div><input type='text' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
      <div><input type='text' value={null} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
      <div><input type='text' value={undefined} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
      <hr/>  
      <div><input type='text' defaultValue={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
      <p>{this.state.value}</p>
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <TestComponent />,
  document.body
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

The first one `input` with specifying string value property. when I type something, call `handleValueChange` function, and the result is `hello world` + `your type thing's first character`.

The second one `input` with empty string value property. when I type something, it calls `handleValueChange` function, but finally, it always gives me one character.

It's weird.

**updated!**
I add a `input` with `defaultValue`, compare with `value={this.state.value}`, my head is mess up..

Comment: Try to delete **value={''}** in your second input. Because everytime handleValueChange event called, its value will be reset

Comment: If none of the answers are correct, I'm not sure what you actually want to do. What's the usecase of having `value={''}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment below your question: remove `value={''}` since this will empty the input everytime it's rendered.

From the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html), the correct way to do it is

```
return <div>
  <input type='text' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/>
  <p>{this.state.value}</p>
</div>
```

This way whenever you type something in the input-area, you'll update the value set in state.

If you want to render the component with a value set in state, you could use:

```
getInitialState() {
  return { value: 'Your default value'}
}
```

Or, as already suggested, use `defaultValue`.

Read more here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

---

Update:

According to your updated question, I think you'll have to understand what setting a value during render function actually does. Whenever you set a value during render function, you'll "lock" the input field to be that specific value. Meaning the user input will have no effect on the rendered element. From the docs: `"User input will have no effect on the rendered element because React has declared the value"`.

To solve this problem, you'll have to set the value to be something you can change dynamically, in your case that will be `value` or `this.state.value`. Like you've done in your third example:

```
<input type='text' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/>
```

This way React accept the value provided by the user input and will then update the value of the  component thereafter.

I still think the docs specifies this pretty clearly, and I think you should read the provided documentation in my original answer.

---

Update 2

To clearify the part with `controlled` and `uncontrolled` components little bit:

A `controlled` component is a component that has a `value` property assigned, and will reflect the value from the user input (the `value prop`).

While an `uncontrolled` component does not have any `value` property assigned, and will NOT reflect the value from the user input (since it does not provide any `value prop`). But if you want to instantiate an `uncontrolled` component with a value, you should use `defaultValue`.

In your case (since you try to use a CONTROLLED component) this means that you should NOT use `defaultValue`, and stick with a correct implementation of a `controlled` component. That is an implementation using `value={this.state.value}`.

Again I recommend reading the docs provided. It's actually not that difficult if you manage to understand the docs.

Hope this clearifies some of you problems! :)

Comment: But, why I update `this.state.value`, the `defaultValue` not change?
I change the third example input value, the last input with `defaultValue` is not change.

Answer (score 3):

use `defaultValue` instead of `value`

```
render() {
return <div>
  <div><input type='text' defaultValue={'hello world'} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
  <div><input type='text' defaultValue={''} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
  <div><input type='text' defaultValue={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
  <div><input type='text' defaultValue={null} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
  <div><input type='text' defaultValue={undefined} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/></div>
  <p>{this.state.value}</p>
 </div>
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only correct `controlled component` here is:

`<input type='text' value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleValueChange}/>`

The others are **not** controlled. However, because the others are calling `setState` and changing the value too, they are affecting the third input.

See what happens:

- First input will call `setState` with `e.target.value = hello world + first character you typed`. So that will be the new value of the third input
- Second input will call `setState` with only one character since the value of that input is always `''`. So one character will be the new value of the third input
- Fourth input the same as the second one
- Last input, since the value is set to `undefined`... That is the same as if you don't define any value there, so the fourth input will not be controlled but every time you type it's copying it's actual value to the third input

Conclusion:

- To get a controlled input, always set the value to something you control it's change (state or props).
- Be careful when changing the same part of the state using different inputs... It becomes really complicated to reason about.